# FinalBuilder 7 compatibility with windows 10

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, finalbuilder, finalbuilder7

I currently have a windows xp machine that is running FinalBuilder 7 and I'm thinking of upgrading to Windows 10 soon, but I do not know if they are compatible.  The [latest patch notes](https://www.finalbuilder.com/downloads/finalbuilder/finalbuilder-7-version-history) that I could find mention an update with implied support for windows 8 (v 2995), but nothing else regarding windows versions past that.

Has anyone had any experience with running FinalBuilder 7 on windows 10?

Comment: This is a question for superuser.com

Comment: I'll post it over there as well, thanks

Comment: @sixtytrees: No, it doesn't. FinalBuilder is a programmers tool, used to automate software builds. Questions about it are entirely on-topic here. Perhaps you should refrain from commenting regarding subjects with which you're not familiar. See the [help/on-topic] pages to refresh your understanding of the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes FinalBuilder 7 runs on windows 10. I'm not aware of any specific changes made to accomodate windows 10.